# $(x_1+\cdots +x_n)^{k}=\sum\limits_{|\beta|=k}\binom{k}{\beta}x^{\beta}$

Tags: combinatorics

> $(x_1+\cdots + x_n)^{k}=\sum\limits_{|\beta|=k}\binom{k}{\beta}x^{\beta}$

I have to prove this by induction on $k$, not on $n$. Do you have a proof without much text, I mean an algebraic proof not combinatorial. This question may have been asked several times but I didn't see any straightforward proof.

Comment: Using the binomial theorem as a start, do induction on $n$.

Comment: $(x_1+\ldots +x_n)^k = \sum_{b_1 = 1}^n\sum_{b_2 = 1}^n \ldots \sum_{b_k = 1}^n \prod_{i=1}^k x_{b_i}  =\displaystyle \sum_{a_1+\ldots+a_n = k} {a \choose n} \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{a_j}$ where in $\sum_{a_1+\ldots+a_n = k} $ the order counts and each $a_j \ge 0$ and ${a \choose n}  = \prod_{j=1}^n { n-\sum_{m<j} a_j \choose a_m}$ is the number of ways of choosing the places..

Comment: Would you find a double induction acceptable, one that inducts on both $n$ and $k$?

Comment: @Michael Burr so you need an induction on $n$ to give an induction proof on $k$ ? If so why not

Comment: What goes wrong if you just mimic the proof of the binomial theorem and consider $(x_1+\cdots+x_n)^{k+1}=(x_1+\cdots+x_n)(x_1+\cdots+x_n)^k=(x_1+\cdots+x_n)\sum_{|\beta|=k}\binom{k}{\beta}x^\beta$?  That $|\beta|=k$ should be a subscript, but it isn't showing up correctly on my screen...